# Extract zip file from react native project folder on initial running

Tags: react-native, zip, unzip

We want to include zip file on react native project, for example in `project/src/assets/zip` folder, include it in the build and extract it to local phone storage on initial App run.

What we want to achieve is, suppose we have a web page that we want to show on react native app. We can decrease the loading time by including the asset for the web page on the project, then told the web page to search for the assets file locally.

We have successfully showing web page with local assets downloaded from internet, in zip format. But We haven’t found on how to achieve the same using zip file on local project.

We have try to import the asset file, then unzip it directly like below with no luck

```
import zipFile from './assets/zip/file.zip'
import * as RNFS from 'react-native-fs'
import { unzip } from 'react-native-zip-archive'

...

componentDidMount() {
  const destination = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/'
  unzip(zipFile, destination)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

We have try to use [react-native-local-resource](https://github.com/IgorBelyayev/React-Native-Local-Resource) to get the file with several combinations without luck too

```
import zipFile from './assets/zip/file.zip'
import * as RNFS from 'react-native-fs'
import { unzip } from 'react-native-zip-archive'
import loadLocalResource from 'react-native-local-resource'

...

componentDidMount() {
  const destination = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/'
  loadLocalResource(assetsZip)
    .then((fileContent) => unzip(fileContent, destination))
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

---

```
import zipFile from './assets/zip/file.zip'
import * as RNFS from 'react-native-fs'
import { unzip } from 'react-native-zip-archive'
import loadLocalResource from 'react-native-local-resource'

...

componentDidMount() {
  const destination = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/'
  const fileName = 'file.zip'
  loadLocalResource(assetsZip)
    .then((fileContent) => RNFS.writeFile(destination + fileName, fileContent))
    .then(() => unzip(destination + fileName, destination))
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

How can We extract zip file on project folder into Phone Storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

while the previous answer was working on debug version of the app, it seems to break on production, because on production `resource.uri` return `file://` uri instead of `http://` as in debug version.

to fix the problem we need to check whether it was `file` uri or `http` url. then use copy function on [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) instead of download function, if it was `file` uri.

```
import zipFile from './assets/zip/file.zip'
import * as RNFS from 'react-native-fs'
import { unzip } from 'react-native-zip-archive'
import resolveAssetSource from 'react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetSource'

...

componentDidMount() {
  const destination = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/'
  const filename = 'file.zip'

  const resource = resolveAssetSource(zipFile)
  const fileUri = resource.uri

  this.loadZipFile(fileUri, destination + filename)
    .then((result) => unzip(destination + filename, destination))
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
}

loadZipFile = (fileUri, destinationFile) = {
  if (fileUri.startWith('file://')) {
    return RNFS.copyFile(fileUri, destinationFile)
  } else {
    const downloadOptions = {
      fromUrl: fileUri,
      toFile: destinationFile
    }

    return RNFS.downloadFile(downloadOptions).promise
  }
}
```

this should work on both production and debug version, even sending zip file using code push was working fine on our case.

**OLD ANSWER:**

After looking on [react-native-local-resource](https://github.com/IgorBelyayev/React-Native-Local-Resource) source code, We come up with some Idea.

The problem with [react-native-local-resource](https://github.com/IgorBelyayev/React-Native-Local-Resource) in our case is, that the final result was `text`, but zip file is not a `text`. So we try to intercept the code in the middle to get zip file as we want.

After some experiment, we follow [react-native-local-resource](https://github.com/IgorBelyayev/React-Native-Local-Resource) code until we got the `uri` of the file, then use [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) to download the file into local storage folder, then unzip those file.

Here is sample of working code on our case

```
import zipFile from './assets/zip/file.zip'
import * as RNFS from 'react-native-fs'
import { unzip } from 'react-native-zip-archive'
import resolveAssetSource from 'react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetSource'

...

componentDidMount() {
  const destination = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/'
  const filename = 'file.zip'

  const resource = resolveAssetSource(zipFile)
  const fileUri = resource.uri

  const downloadOptions = {
    fromUrl: fileUri,
    toFile: destination + filename
  }

  RNFS.downloadFile(downloadOptions).promise
    .then((result) => unzip(destination + filename, destination))
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

Hope it can help anyone who have meet the same problem